# .NET- Treeview Control

Tags: c#, .net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<properties>
    <general>
        <title type="textbox">title1</title>
        <subtitle type="textbox">subtitle1</subtitle>
        <radius type="textbox">20</radius>
    </general>
    <behavior>
        <sorting>
            <enable type="checkbox">True</enable>
            <by type="dropdown">Data</by>
            <order type="dropdown">Descending</order>
        </sorting>
    </behavior>
    <appearance>
        <series>
            <innerseries type="colorpicker">#996666</innerseries>
            <innerseries type="colorpicker"></innerseries>
            <innerseries type="colorpicker"></innerseries>
            <transparency type="slider">19</transparency>
        </series>
    </appearance>
</properties>
```

Above is my XML.

In My .ASPX Page:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1"  runat="server" 
    OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged1"  ImageSet="Arrows"       
    EnableTheming="true">
</asp:TreeView>  
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

In my Codebehind I dynamically load an xml and build a treeview

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   doc.LoadXml("XmlFile");
      XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement;
       TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
       TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(doc.DocumentElement.Name));

       TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
       tNode = TreeView1.Nodes[0];

       Property obj = new Property();
       obj.AddChildNode(node, tNode);
       }

       In my Property.cs  (Class File)

       public void AddChildNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
    {
        XmlNode xNode;
        TreeNode tNode;
        XmlNodeList nodeList;
        int i;

        // Loop through the XML nodes until the leaf is reached.
        // Add the nodes to the TreeView during the looping process.
        //if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)

        if (inXmlNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1 && inXmlNode.ChildNodes[0].HasChildNodes)
        {

            nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;

            for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];


                inTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));

                tNode = inTreeNode.ChildNodes[i];
                AddChildNode(xNode, tNode);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (inXmlNode.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
            {
                nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;

                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];


                    inTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));

                    tNode = inTreeNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    AddChildNode(xNode, tNode);

                }
            }
            // Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
            // type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
            else
            {

                if (inXmlNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
                {

                    inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.Name).Trim();
                    inTreeNode.Target = inXmlNode.Attributes[0].Value;





                }
                else
                {
                    inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.Name).Trim();
                    inTreeNode.Target = inXmlNode.Attributes[0].Value;
                    inTreeNode.Value = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[0].Value;
                }
            }
            //inTreeNode.Value = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim();

        }
}
```

The Problem here is, when i run my code and select the Title or Subtile node,the focus is set to that node and SelectIndexChanged event is fired.But, when i select the First Child (Innerseries )it wirks perfectly.When second Innerseries Child is selected,the selection is focused on that node.But, when i Select the Third Child(Innereseries), the focus is on the Second Child .So, it looks like when the node name and value are same ,it selects the first node .

Comment: what you want to do please clarify ?

Comment: That is not how it works, something else is happening. Show us you code; where you create and add the TreeViewItem to the tree and the tree events.